# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase' not found

Tags: magento2

Whilst running `php bin/magento setup:di:compile` we are getting the error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase' not found /path/to/test/class
```

Answer (score 0):

### Background

By default Magento will automatically exclude the directories `tests` and `Test` from [module](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Console/Command/DiCompileCommand.php#L236) and [library](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Console/Command/DiCompileCommand.php#L271) paths. As they shouldn't be needed when compiling the application.

If you are getting this error because your test class is in a different directory, e.g `test` then the best option would be to change the name of the directory to one of the auto excluded directories.

### Solution

The issue we had was that a module was including a library like this:

```
ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::LIBRARY, 'VENDOR/MODULE', __DIR__ . '/../../VENDOR/MODULE');
```

This meant that the auto generated exclude path was:

```
^(?:/home/magento/htdocs/vendor/\.\./\.\./VENDOR/MODULE)/([\w]+/)?tests
```

(I've stripped bits out to make more obvious)
which did not match:

```
/home/magento/htdocs/vendor/VENDOR/MODULE/tests/UserAgentTest.php
```

The fix was to change the registration of the library to be an absolute path not a relative one

```
ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::LIBRARY, 'VENDOR/MODULE', realpath(__DIR__ . '/../../VENDOR/MODULE'));
```

This gave us an exclude path of:

```
^(?:/home/magento/htdocs/vendor/VENDOR/MODULE)/([\w]+/)?tests
```

Which did match the path to the test class and meant it was skipped in compilation.

Hope this saves someone some time :D